# Get number of days as number in moment.js with x.fromNow();

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, countdown

I use Moment.js

```
var created = moment("24.07.2015 16:09:05", "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss");
var expire= created.add(7, 'days');
var countdown = expire.fromNow();
```

var countdown gives me the string "in 3 days" - but how can I get only a number in days or in hours without the string "in days". 
I want to do a comparison and mark the countdown in different colors, when its smaller than 7, or 4 or 1 day.

Comment: I recommend that you revise your question because at the moment it is a bit cryptic.

Comment: @Petrichor I edited it.

Comment: It makes way more sense now -- nice one!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`moment.duration`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/):

```
var created = moment("24.07.2015 16:09:05", "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss");
var expires = created.clone().add(7, 'days');

var now = new Date;
var dur = moment.duration({ from: now, to: expires });

console.log(dur.humanize()); // => "3 days"
console.log(dur.asDays()); // => 3.0729382175925926
```

This is exactly what `fromNow` does [behind the scenes](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/25cc720fbaab7323a1016cd0beb6a36e349c41be/src/lib/moment/from.js#L8). You can use any Date or moment object for the `from` and `to` options, so if e.g. you want to get the time between now and `expires`, you would do `moment.duration({ from: new Date, to: expires })`.

Comment: OP wants the duration from now, not from created.  `var dur = moment.duration({ from: moment(), to: expires } );`  Also asked for days:  `console.log(dur.asDays());`

Comment: Okay. I'm pretty sure OP can figure out how to use `new Date` instead of `create` for the `from` option.